# Polar coordinate system of DE's to be written in cartesian form.

Tags: dynamical-systems, coordinate-systems

Suppose we have a system in polar coordinates:

$\dot r = -r$ and $\dot \theta = \frac{1}{\ln{r}}$, we are asked to solve for $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ explicitly, so I just integrated both equations so that $r = Ae^{-t}$ and $\theta(t) = \frac{t}{\ln r} + C$ where $A,C$ are constants.

How would I write this system in terms of x and y?

Comment: You are supposed to write $\theta(t)$ as a function of $t$, not $t$ and $r(t)$ (and your formula for $\theta(t)$ is wrong anyway). Can you do that?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: cna you post the original problem please?

Comment: I am not sure of the reason why you are not sure what I mean since what I mean is crystal clear: you are supposed to write $\theta(t)$ as a function of $t$ alone and you did not, please do that.

Comment: I nmeant, how do you do that.

Comment: must I substitute r(t) for r in the $\theta(t)$ equation?

Comment: Someone please help :/

Comment: Once you have $r(t)$ as a function of $t$, substitute it in the equation for $\dot\theta(t)$ and solve for $\theta(t)$.